# How to kill specific java process?

Tags: kill

`ps -aux | less` displays

```
java -jar /var/appname.jar
```

Now I'm killing it by

```
killall -9 java
```

But if there is also another java process `java -jar /var/anotherappname.jar` how to kill only the first one?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest using `pkill`, with the `-f` flag to match against the whole command:

```
pkill -f /var/appname.jar
```

Test first with

```
pgrep -af /var/appname.jar
```

From `man pkill`:

```
   -f, --full
          The pattern is normally only matched against the  process  name.
          When -f is set, the full command line is used.
```

Comment: I can't get `pgrep` to work if it's just a class name, such as one running through the IDE.  Anyone have success?  e.g. `26126 ??         0:07.15 java [...] com.github.MySillyClass`. 

Searching for the process using `pgrep -af com.github.MySillyClass` isn't working.